# Keep aspect ratio but rotate it in darktable

Tags: photo-editing, darktable, cropping

Is it possible to rotate the crop frame, i.e. crop a landscape photo to portrait and vice versa? I would like to keep the original aspect ratio of the photo, just change the orientation. And obviously, I am not rotating the actual image. All search results are about rotating the image and cropping to the same orientation.

To clarify: this is about using **darktable**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The old Crop and Rotate module allows changing the aspect ratio of a crop between portrait and landscape orientation:

> Finally, the button beside the aspect combobox allows you to switch between portrait and landscape orientation if you have selected a rectangular aspect ratio [source](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/3.8/en/module-reference/processing-modules/crop-rotate/)

The new [Crop](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/3.8/en/module-reference/processing-modules/crop/) module has similar functionality.

- As of Darktable 3.8, the Crop and Rotate module is deprecated. Two modules, a Crop module and a Rotate module replace it to improve the pixel pipeline. Crop is applied late. Rotate is applied early.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot upvote here but this is the solution. Particularly: "Finally, the button beside the aspect combobox allows you to switch between portrait and landscape orientation". I have honestly clicked on it a few times with no result so could not understand what it was for. Now I went and purposefully set myself up and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you will end up with a dramatically smaller photo than you started with.

Let's say you start with a portrait photo which is 3000 pixels high by 2000 pixels wide, so an aspect ratio of 1.5:1 (the actual pixel numbers don't matter here). If you want to keep the same aspect ratio but as a landscape picture, the best you can do is to keep it 2000 pixels wide, but now with a height of 2000 *divided* by 1.5, or 1333 pixels high - or 44% of the original size. More generally, if your original photo had an aspect ratio of :1, you will get to keep 1∕² of your original photo.

I'm not a Darktable user, but even if it doesn't have a way of directly doing this you now have the maths to work it out youself; alternatively, you can get the same effect by rotating the image, cropping to the original aspect ratio and then rotating again.